# Analyze: Why a query taking could take so long, seems costs are low?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I am having these results for analyze for a simple query that does not return more than 150 records from tables less than 200 records most of them, as I have a table that stores latest value and the other fields are FK of the data.

Update: see the new results from same query some our later. The site is not public and/or there should be not users right now as it is in development.

```
 explain analyze
SELECT lv.station_id,
    s.name AS station_name,
    s.latitude,
    s.longitude,
    s.elevation,
    lv.element_id,
    e.symbol AS element_symbol,
    u.symbol,
    e.name AS element_name,
    lv.last_datetime AS datetime,
    lv.last_value AS valor,
    s.basin_id,
    s.municipality_id
   FROM (((element_station lv /*350 records*/
     JOIN stations s ON ((lv.station_id = s.id))) /*40 records*/
     JOIN elements e ON ((lv.element_id = e.id))) /*103 records*/
     JOIN units u ON ((e.unit_id = u.id))) /* 32 records */
  WHERE s.id = lv.station_id AND e.id = lv.element_id AND lv.interval_id = 6 and
lv.last_datetime >= ((now() - '06:00:00'::interval) - '01:00:00'::interval)
```

I have already tried `VACUUM` and after that some is saved, but again after some times it goes up.  I have implemented an index on the fields.

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..2654.66 rows=1 width=92) (actual time=1219.390..35296.253 rows=157 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (e.unit_id = u.id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 4867
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..2652.93 rows=1 width=92) (actual time=1219.383..35294.083 rows=157 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (lv.element_id = e.id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 16014
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..2648.62 rows=1 width=61) (actual time=1219.301..35132.373 rows=157 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on element_station lv  (cost=0.00..2640.30 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=1219.248..1385.517 rows=157 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((interval_id = 6) AND (last_datetime >= ((now() - '06:00:00'::interval) - '01:00:00'::interval)))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 168
              ->  Index Scan using stations_pkey on stations s  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=3.471..214.941 rows=1 loops=157)
                    Index Cond: (id = lv.station_id)
        ->  Seq Scan on elements e  (cost=0.00..3.03 rows=103 width=35) (actual time=0.003..0.999 rows=103 loops=157)
  ->  Seq Scan on units u  (cost=0.00..1.32 rows=32 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=32 loops=157)
Planning time: 8.312 ms
Execution time: 35296.427 ms
```

update, same query running it tonight; no changes:

```
Sort  (cost=601.74..601.88 rows=55 width=92) (actual time=1.822..1.841 rows=172 loops=1)
  Sort Key: lv.last_datetime DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 52kB
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=11.60..600.15 rows=55 width=92) (actual time=0.287..1.680 rows=172 loops=1)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=11.31..248.15 rows=55 width=51) (actual time=0.263..0.616 rows=172 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (e.unit_id = u.id)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=9.59..245.60 rows=75 width=51) (actual time=0.225..0.528 rows=172 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (lv.element_id = e.id)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on element_station lv  (cost=5.27..240.25 rows=75 width=20) (actual time=0.150..0.359 rows=172 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: ((last_datetime >= ((now() - '06:00:00'::interval) - '01:00:00'::interval)) AND (interval_id = 6))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=22
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on element_station_latest  (cost=0.00..5.25 rows=75 width=0) (actual time=0.136..0.136 rows=226 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((last_datetime >= ((now() - '06:00:00'::interval) - '01:00:00'::interval)) AND (interval_id = 6))
                    ->  Hash  (cost=3.03..3.03 rows=103 width=35) (actual time=0.062..0.062 rows=103 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 15kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on elements e  (cost=0.00..3.03 rows=103 width=35) (actual time=0.006..0.031 rows=103 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.32..1.32 rows=32 width=8) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=32 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on units u  (cost=0.00..1.32 rows=32 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=32 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using stations_pkey on stations s  (cost=0.29..6.39 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=172)
              Index Cond: (id = lv.station_id)
Planning time: 2.390 ms
Execution time: 2.009 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the misestimate of the number of rows in the sequential scan on `element_station`. Either autoanalyze has kicked in and calculated new statistics for the table or the data changed.

The problem is probably that PostgreSQL doesn't know the result of

```
((now() - '06:00:00'::interval) - '01:00:00'::interval)
```

at query planning time.

If that is possible for you, do it in two steps: First, calculate the expression above (either in PostgreSQL or on the client side). Then run the query with the result as a constant. That will make it easier for PostgreSQL to estimate the result count.

Comment: Thanks you, is basically getting the records updated in the last hour, I will do that..  Seem wierd that navicat shows that element_station table has 70k rows, could this be mistaken the query ?

Comment: In the first query, `element_station` has 325 rows (157 + 168). The problem is not that there are many rows, but that PostgreSQL guesses the number of result rows wrongly.

Comment: Hi, I used that approach and from javascript calculate the timestamp the last hour and compare with the value as a parameters, performance issues persists, I restart postgresql and is is fast, also with prior original approach to determine values from the database.  But after some time goes slow, so what would be the best to check out  now?  Other parts / queries of the DB seems working fine.

Comment: If the statement is inside a PL/pgSQL function or you are using a prepared statement, it could be the "generic plan" kicking in. The symptoms would be slow execution from the sixth execution in a database session on (with JDBC and prepared statements, from the eleventh execution on). You may want to ask a new question for that.